# Caffe error: Number of labels must match number of predictions

Tags: machine-learning, caffe

I use AlexNet for images multiclass (9 classes) classification. Dataset saved in hdf5 format and have a shape [image, vector_of_lenght_9].
When I start train network following error occurs:

```
F1213 11:17:13.133412 50200 accuracy_layer.cpp:31] Check failed: outer_num_ * inner_num_ == bottom[1]->count() (1 vs. 9) Number of labels must match number of predictions; e.g., if label axis == 1 and prediction shape is (N, C, H, W), label count (number of labels) must be N*H*W, with integer values in {0, 1, ..., C-1}.
*** Check failure stack trace:
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is my file with network (train_val.prototxt):

```
name: "AlexNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "train.txt"
    batch_size: 1

  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "test.txt"
    batch_size: 1

  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 11
    stride: 4
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "norm1"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "norm1"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "norm1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "norm2"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "norm2"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "norm2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "conv3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}
layer {
  name: "conv4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv4"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv4"
}
layer {
  name: "fc6"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "fc6"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu6"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
}
layer {
  name: "drop6"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc7"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc7"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu7"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
}
layer {
  name: "drop7"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc8"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc8"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1000
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

Here is solver file:

```
net: "train_val.prototxt"
test_iter: 1000
test_interval: 1000
base_lr: 0.01
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 100000
display: 20
max_iter: 450000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "caffe_alexnet_train"
solver_mode: CPU
```

The first version contained error that dataset had format [image, class_label]. The output result was wrong but network trained without any error. Output of network has format of vector of length 9. So when shapes of output and label were different everything was ok (although it shouldn't). When they are the same error occurs.

Comment: what are you trying to do here? predict one of 9 classes per image, or predict nine different attributes per image? why your labels are **vectors** of length 9? what are the values of the labels? Are they "1-hot" vectors?

Comment: I try to predict the class to which an image belongs. The output should be a vector which contain probability of belonging to each class. So the labels used for training should have a shape like [0 0 ... 1  0 ... 0]

Comment: For training you should not use "1 hot" vector for labels (i.e., vectors of the form `[0, 0, 1, 0 ...]`) but rather the **integer** label you want to predict. So, instead of label `[0, 1, 0 ...]` you simply set `label=1`. Your labels are integers in the range 0..8 one label per image. You also need to change `num_output` of `fc8` to 9 instead of 1000.